# Apache reverser proxy fails when submitting an HTML form

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, zope

I folks,

I want to build this scenario: one **public server** (openSuSE + Apache2 + Zope/Plone) and other **private server** with web applications (openSuSE + Apache2 + Zope/Plone).

I want users think they are working only with one server (SSO is already configured and works fine).

I installed **mod_proxy_html** in public server. And now I can 'route' traffic between the servers except only when the application submit an HTML form. In this case the URL changes to the private server.

```
RewriteRule ^/Intranet/Apps/app1(.*) http://private.dom.com:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/private.dom.com:80/CELLS/VirtualHostRoot/Intranet/Apps/app1/$1 [L,P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://public.dom.com:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/public.dom.com:80/DOM/VirtualHostRoot/

ProxyHTMLDoctype XHTML
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE;proxy-html;INFLATE
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://private.dom.com http://public.dom.com

ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain .private.dom.com .public.dom.com
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or what I miss to configure :-(

Thanks in advance,
Oscar.

Comment: What is your version of mod_proxy_html? Newer versions need `ProxyHTMLEnable On` to activate the module.

Comment: I'm using version 3.1.2 and I think that only needs to put: SetOutputFilter proxy-html

Comment: Adding ProxyHTMLEnable On I have the same problem. Without this directive the behavior was the same, as I can saw in logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I see the light!

The only I need is this:

```
RewriteRule ^/Intranet/Apps/app1(.*) http://private.dom.com:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/%{HTTP_HOST}:80/DOM/VirtualHostRoot/Intranet/Apps/app1/$1 [L,P] 
ProxyPassReverse / http://private.dom.com:8080/VirtualHostBase/http/%{HTTP_HOST}:80/DOM/VirtualHostRoot/
```

And the key of this issue is on adding **%{HTTP_HOST}** (an Apache2 variable), disable the Apache2 in the private server, and the work will be done by the *VirtualHostMonster* on the private server.

Thanks for all of your comments and regards!
Oscar.